# Когда НЕ нужно использовать SOLID?

Tags: ооп, архитектура, solid

Читал, что SOLID - это хорошие рекомендации, проверенные временем, но пихать их в каждый проект не стоит. Гуглил примеры, когда его применять не нужно и не нашел. Скажите, в каких случаях применение SOLID неоправданно?

Comment: рискну предположить что поступать следует так же как с применением патернов проектирования, т.е. когда следованием рекомендациям не усложняет код

Comment: С применением SOLID количество классов в моем проекте увеличилось с 5 до 20. Я совсем недавно начал заниматься проектированием и меня пугает такое обилие классов. Можно ли по количеству классов оценивать сложность кода?

Comment: только на основании *количества* классов сложно сказать. уточните пожалуйста какой из принципов [`SOLID`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) привел к увеличению количества классов с 5 до 20?

Comment: @RareScrap разделение обязанностей модулей и подмодулей это хорошо, так как их можно переиспользовать, а по поводу SOLID - главное не использовать избыточность при разделении классов, чтобы лишний раз не переписывать. И сложность кода оценивается не по количеству классов

Comment: @Bald К увеличению числа классов привел принцип LSP и DIP

Comment: @RareScrap См. ответы Sergey Teplyakov - он очень опытный проектировщик из Microsoft  . От себя добавлю: мне лично очень не нравится, что под SOLID подразумеваются принципы(а принципы как известно не нарушают), хотя по факту - это скорее рекомендации, техники для построения архитектуры больших приложений. Попытайтесь предсказать: в положительную или отрицательную сторону изменится проект после следования определённому принципу в определённом месте - это и будет ответом, следовать ли ему.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Касательно любого паттерна/принципа разработки можно сказать:

- Если вы следуете ему, **нет гарантии**, что ваш код автоматически станет более корректным, расширяемым и сопровождаемым.
- Если вы не следуете ему, **нет гарантии**, что ваш код автоматически становится проблемным, не расширяемым и не сопровождаемым.
- Следуя ему вы можете решить одну из проблем своего кода (или не решить), но создать **новые** проблемы.

Также имеет место быть неполное или даже некорректное понимание используемых принципов/паттернов. И возможно даже возведение в абсолют, когда буквальное следование им становится превыше здравого смысла.

Таким образом вопрос не в том, когда не нужно использовать SOLID, а в том, насколько использовать каждый из его принципов в своем, конкретном случае.

### S - Single Responsibility Principle

*Класс должен иметь только одну ответственность*

При недостаточном разделении ответственности получаем антипаттерн "god", класс становиться кухонным комбайном. В то же время при чрезмерном разделении код может раздробится так, что в каждом классе остается чуть ли не один метод, состоящий из одной строки кода. В итоге сложность восприятия может увеличиться.

### O - Open/Closed Principle

*Программные сущности должны быть открытыми для расширения, но закрытыми для модификации*

Возьмем ситуацию, когда базовый класс содержит общие детали реализации, а несколько наследников уточняют её. Следуя этому принципу, при добавлении новых потомков, их общие черты придется выносить в один промежуточный класс, чтобы не трогать базовый. Со временем может образоваться причудливая иерархия, хотя, вероятно, стоило рассмотреть вариант модификации базового класса (несмотря на возможные поломки уже имеющихся потомков).

### L - Liskov Substitution Principle

*Объекты в программе должны быть заменяемыми на экземпляры их подтипов без изменения правильности выполнения программы*

Ради обеспечения этого принципа иногда приходится использовать сомнительные решения. К примеру класс `Ellipse` имеет подкласс `Circle`, который является случаем `Ellipse` с одинаковой длиной по осям `X` и `Y`. В соответствии с принципом, подкласс `Circle` обязан реализовать поведение родителя. Если `Ellipse` содержит метод `stretchX`, позволяющий модифицировать длину по оси `X`, то класс `Cirlce` также обязан реализовать это поведение, несмотря на то, что для круга это невозможно.

### I - Interface Segregation Principle

*Много интерфейсов, специально предназначенных для клиентов, лучше, чем один интерфейс общего назначения*

Требует, чтобы клиенты не зависели от интерфейсов, которые они не используют. На практике, особенно при плохо продуманной архитектуре, это может вылиться в дробление на очень мелкие интерфейсы из одного-двух методов, чтобы удовлетворить множество клиентов.

### D - Dependency Inversion Principle

*Принцип инверсии зависимости*

Возьмем ситуацию когда объект класса `A` вызывает методы объекта класса `B`. Значит `A` зависит от `B`. С применением этого принципа, объект типа `B` должен быть инстанциирован вне `A` и передан как зависимость в `A`. Без применения этого принципа, это может сделать сам объект `A`, что во многих случаях гораздо удобнее.

---

Основано на http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/not-so-solid-oo-principles.html. В процессе чтения узнал много нового. Холивар приветствуется )

Comment: В качестве холивара: «_при добавлении новых потомков, их общие черты придется выносить в один промежуточный класс, чтобы не трогать базовый_» — Не согласен. Промежуточные классы нельзя добавлять только для того, чтобы расшарить код! Для расшаривания кода нужно пользоваться композицией, а не наследованием, выносить общие куски во вспомогательные классы. Иерархия классов должна отражать предметную область, а не подробности имплементации.

Comment: @VladD даже если выносить реализацию в композицию, к предметной области также могут появится новые требования в виде новых интерфейсов. Плюс такой вынос реализации (если требуется доступ ко многим приватным данным) может только усложнить код передачей этих данных.

Comment: Приватные данные тоже имеет смысл вынести во вспомогательный класс. Если данные используются в режиме «каждая часть кода пользуется каждым куском данных», то это сложнее, но такое использование — признак проблем в дизайне и отсутствия внутренней структуры.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian пример и вывод из него для Liskov Substitution Principle неверен. Применение LSP к примеру круг/эллипис (квадрат/прямоугольник) дает результат "круг и эллипс не должны наследоваться друг от друга".

Comment: @VladimirGamalian если точнее - то наличие методов `stretchX`/`stretchY` скорее приведет к вызову `stretchX(2);stretchY(2)` в коде. Что, при вызове на эллипсе растянет его в два раза во все стороны, а при вызове на круге - или не растянет совсем, или растянет в 4 раза - т.е. правильность работы при использовании экзепмпляра Circle как Ellipse в любом случае будет нарушена.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian IS - формулировка странная. "Требует, чтобы клиенты не зависели от интерфейсов, которые они не используют" - ну так удалить зависимость, всего делов :) Суть принципа - в создании специфических интерфейсов под каждый способ использования (под каждый вид клиента) - а не смешивание всех методов в один огромный интерфейс.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian - по LSP - наверное, стоит дописать часть про " but using this method would result in a shape which is no longer a circle."

Answer (score 13):

Как и любой инструмент, принципы проектирования нужно применять с умом.

Можно выделить два случая, когда применение принципов проектирования приведет к увеличению проблем, и не приведет ни к чему хорошему.

1. YAGNI

   *Подробности — в ответе на вопрос «[Нарушает ли OCP и DIP (из SOLID) принцип YAGNI?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556137/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-ocp-%D0%B8-dip-%D0%B8%D0%B7-solid-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-yagni/556526#556526)».*

   Принципы проектирования предназначены для смягчения определенной проблемы разработки (да, именно «смягчения», но не решения проблемы), добавляя при этом свои собственные проблемы.

   Поскольку иногда проблемы программисты придумывают себе сами, то следование (особенно буквальное) принципам проектирования приведет к перекосу дизайна, не решая при этом реальной проблемы.

   Другими словами, чрезмерное увлечения принципами проектирования может привести к переусложненному решению там, где эта сложность не нужна.
2. «over»-SOLID

   *Подробнее в статье «[О принципах проектирования](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/10/about-design-principles.html)».*

   Есть ряд типовых паталогических случаев использования SOLID-принципов:

   - **Anti-SRP** – Принцип размытой ответственности. Классы разбиты на множество мелких классов, в результате чего логика размазывается по нескольким классам/модулям.
   - **Anti-OCP** – Принцип фабрики фабрик. Дизайн является слишком обобщенным и расширябельным, выделяется слишком большое число уровней абстракции.
   - **Anti-LCP** – Принцип непонятного наследования. Принцип проявляется либо в чрезмерном количестве наследования, либо в его полном отсутствии, в зависимости от опыта и взглядов местного главного архитектора.
   - **Anti-ISP** – Принцип тысячи интерфейсов. Интерфейсы классов разбиваются на слишком большое число составляющих, что делает их неудобными для использования всеми клиентами.
   - **Anti-DIP** – Принцип инверсии сознания или DI-головного мозга. Интерфейсы выделяются для каждого класса и пачками передаются через конструкторы. Понять, где находится логика становится практически невозможно.